# show devices connected with raspberry pi in poky distribution (Yocto Project)

Tags: raspberry-pi, embedded, bitbake, openembedded

How can show all devices connected to raspberry pi work on poky distribution compiled with bitbake

for example 
i have microphone connected to my RPI by jack slot

in raspbian i can write something like that

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
```

but in poky dist. can not find asound folder

Comment: Most probably, you don't have sound enabled in your Poky kernel configuration. And what you have in your kernel configuration depends on your chosen MACHINE at least. Also, Poky comes in different versions so there is a quesion of what version do you use.

Comment: poky jethro @RomanKhimov

Comment: So, what is the MACHINE you're using for your builds?

Comment: Ubuntu linux 64 bit

Comment: I mean `MACHINE` variable from your local.conf, what's in your local.conf? It very well might be that your kernel doesn't have `CONFIG_SOUND` enabled because your `MACHINE` doesn't have "sound" in its `MACHINE_FEATURES`.

Comment: i am sorry for late

MACHINE = "raspberrypi"

Comment: Are you using [meta-raspberrypi](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-raspberrypi/?h=jethro) layer? That has a specific [kernel recipe](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/meta-raspberrypi/tree/recipes-kernel/linux?h=jethro) with specific config (straight from kernel git) and that config has `CONFIG_SOUND` enabled. What is the output of `bitbake -v virtual/kernel` in your case (you can add that and all the other info (versions, layers, `MACHINE`) into the question)?